# Add array to an object inside of an array in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So say I have an array like so:

```
this.state = {
  students: [{
      "company": "This", 
      "firstName": "Randy", 
      "id": "1", 
      "lastName": "Orton", 
    }, 
    {
      "company": "That", 
      "firstName": "Clark", 
      "id": "2", 
      "lastName": "Kent", 
    }]
}
```

I would like to add an array to the first object so it looks like this.

```
this.state = {
      students: [{
          "company": "This", 
          "firstName": "Randy", 
          "id": "1", 
          "lastName": "Orton", 
          "array" : []
        }, 
        {
          "company": "That", 
          "firstName": "Clark", 
          "id": "2", 
          "lastName": "Kent", 
        }]
    }
```

How can I go about doing that without messing with initial state but only update it?

Comment: Kindly first search thoroughly about what you're looking for before asking question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use these following ways:

```
this.state.students[0].array = [];

this.state.students.find(x => x.company === 'This').array = [];
```

---

After getting the response from server, you can add `array` property to each `student` object immediately:

Example:

```
var obj = {};

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/yourAPIUrl'
}).done(function (response) {
    obj.state = reponse;

    for (var student of obj.state.students) {
        student.array = [];
    }
});
```

Comment: Where will I set this state, as I'm setting up the initial state of students from an API call?

Comment: @Binny.H So, you meant: You want to get the response from server via using API that contains `array` property?

Comment: No, basically the initial state is being set from API call. Which I showed of example above. Then I want to add an empty array to each student object in that array so that I can push elements in that new array later.

Comment: @Binny.H I've updated the answer. Is it what you meant?